# vector not producing expected output c++

Tags: c++

I am creating an idea bank to hold ideas inputted from a keyboard or from a txt file.
the idea follows the following pattern

> ID:
>
> Proposer:
>
> keywords:
>
> content:

i am then implementing an indexing algorithm for the idea bank using reverted index using the following struct

```
struct Index {
string key;
vector<int> idList;
};
```

where key represents a keyword in an idea and idList represent the ID for the idea.

I am then storing the index in an AVL tree.
here is my code to to create the inverted index.

```
void IdeaBank::AVLTreeIndexing(){
     vector<string> kwords_vec;
        vector<int> relevantIDs;
        int foundIdIn;
        string kword;
        Index input;

        for (int loop = 0; loop < newIdea.size(); loop++){
            kwords_vec = newIdea[loop].getKeyword();

            for (int i = 0; i < kwords_vec.size(); i++){
                // goes through all ideas
                for (int j = 0; j < newIdea.size(); j++){
                    if (newIdea[j].foundWordInBoth(kwords_vec[i])){
                        input.key =  kwords_vec[i];
                        input.idList.push_back(newIdea[j].getID());
                        tree.AVL_Insert(input);

                        relevantIDs.push_back(input.idList[j]);
                    }// end of lookfor
                }

            }// end of kwords.size loop
        }

}
```

my logic behind the above function is the following:
1) go through all the ideas and get the keyword
2) check if an idea contains the keyword
3) store the word as a key in my struct and store the ID in my vector in the struct
4) insert the struct into my avl tree

i am then trying to create a search function to print all the ideas that contain the word in their keyword. and this is where i believe i am having problems.
here is the code

```
void IdeaBank::searchQueryFromBank(string word){

Index index;
vector <int> test;


        if (tree.AVL_Retrieve(word, index)){
            cout << "found in tree"<<endl;
            cout << "Relevant idea ID's for "
                 << word << ":" << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < index.idList.size(); i++){
                cout << index.idList[i] << endl;
                test.push_back(index.idList[i]);       
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "No relevant ideas found for " << word << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "displaying the following Ideas"<<endl;
        for (int i=0;i<test.size();i++)
        {
            displayIdeaByID(test[i]);
        }
}
```

the problem i am having:
my ID list vector is being populated with numbers that dont contain the keyword.

for example say i have the two following ideas

> ID: 1
>
> Proposer: bob
>
> keywords: computer,laptop
>
> content: computer with built in microphone
>
> ID: 2
>
> Proposer: bob
>
> keywords: smartphone
>
> content: smartphone with built in microphone

if i was to search for the keyword "smartphone"
my result would print the following ID's

ID 0...

ID 0...

ID 1...

in my indexing function, the function foundWordInBoth is defined as

```
bool Idea::foundWordInBoth(string word){

        if (find(keyword.begin(), keyword.end(), word) != keyword.end()){
        return true;
    }
        size_t pos;
    pos = content.find(word);
    if (pos != string::npos)
    {
        return true;
    }

        return false;
```

the above function checks to see if a word is found in either the keyword or in the contents of the idea.

overall, i am unsure why it is printing out Ideas that do not contain a certain keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the problem is here

```
void IdeaBank::AVLTreeIndexing(){
     vector<string> kwords_vec;
        vector<int> relevantIDs;
        int foundIdIn;
        string kword;
        Index input;

        for (int loop = 0; loop < newIdea.size(); loop++){
            kwords_vec = newIdea[loop].getKeyword();

            for (int i = 0; i < kwords_vec.size(); i++){
                // goes through all ideas
                for (int j = 0; j < newIdea.size(); j++){
                    if (newIdea[j].foundWordInBoth(kwords_vec[i])){
                        input.key =  kwords_vec[i];
                        input.idList.push_back(newIdea[j].getID());
                        tree.AVL_Insert(input);

                        relevantIDs.push_back(input.idList[j]);
                    }// end of lookfor
                }

            }// end of kwords.size loop
        }

}
```

You only declare one `Index` object, which you then push back IDs to for the entire execution of the function. So the list of IDs just builds and builds.

I'm finding the logic a little hard to follow because you only ever seem to have one ID for each key but clearly you need to move the declaration of `input` to some narrower scope.

Maybe it should look something like this (but really I'm guessing)

```
void IdeaBank::AVLTreeIndexing() {
    for (int loop = 0; loop < newIdea.size(); loop++) {
        vector<string> kwords_vec = newIdea[loop].getKeyword();
        for (int i = 0; i < kwords_vec.size(); i++) {
            Index input;
            input.key = kwords_vec[i];
            // goes through all ideas
            for (int j = 0; j < newIdea.size(); j++) {
                if (newIdea[j].foundWordInBoth(kwords_vec[i])) {
                    input.idList.push_back(newIdea[j].getID());
                }// end of lookfor
            }
            tree.AVL_Insert(input);
        }// end of kwords.size loop
    }
}
```

In general get used to declaring variables where you need them, instead of declaring them all at the beginning of a function.

Comment: thankyou, this fixed the issue!
just a quick question, why is it better to declare variables when i need them?
is it just for cleaner code?

Comment: @william_ Cleaner code is the most important reason.